# How can "sequelize.import()" import models from another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I create a new model in the following way:

```
//user.js file
module.exports = function (sequelize, DateTypes) {

return sequelize.define("user", {
    email: {
        type: DateTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: DateTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len: [7, 100]
        }
    }
});
};
```

and into db.js file where i built a new database:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"; // established if you work in production or in development mode
var sequelize;

if (env == "production") {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
        "dialect": "postgres",

    });
} else {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
        'dialect': 'sqlite',
        'storage': __dirname + '/data/dev-todo-api.sqlite' // location where you create a new sqlite database 
    });
}

var db = {};

db.todo = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/todo.js");
db.user = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/user.js");
db.sequelize = sequelize; //contain a settings of database
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I don't understand how user.js knows that `sequelize` (that I insert as a parameter into `module.exports`) is the instance of a sequelize package if it is situated into another file? Maybe because with `sequelize.import('/user.js')` it imports the entire sequelize package?

Comment: Please check your spelling. In the first line you have two errors.

Comment: Thanks...I got my solution from your question :)

Answer (score 10):

See the definition of [`sequelize.import`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/sequelize.js#L643):

```
Sequelize.prototype.import = function(path) {
  // is it a relative path?
  if(Path.normalize(path) !== Path.resolve(path)){
    // make path relative to the caller
    var callerFilename = Utils.stack()[1].getFileName()
      , callerPath = Path.dirname(callerFilename);

    path = Path.resolve(callerPath, path);
  }

  if (!this.importCache[path]) {
    var defineCall = (arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : require(path));
    if (typeof defineCall === 'object' && defineCall.__esModule) {
      // Babel/ES6 module compatability
      defineCall = defineCall['default'];
    }
    this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
  }

  return this.importCache[path];
};
```

Effectively it calls `require` on the path and then calls the result with the sequelize instance as its first argument. This is what ties the knot allowing the module to have a reference to the sequelize instance that imported it.

Comment: Then, with "sequelize.import()", is how to use "require" for receive the models into user.js but the istance "sequelize" of "sequelize.import()" it is passed into path file. Right?

Comment: That is what happens when effectively `require(path)(this, DataTypes)` occurs.

Comment: @DanD. A related question:  when I try to access the `prototype` methods defined on the model outside of the model file, e.g.in my controller, I get `Model.prototype.Yourfunction` is not a function.  would you please help? here is a detailed question asked, if you need more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382550/sequelize-model-prototype-customfunction-not-working

Comment: sequalize.import is deprecated now, now how to do it, with require its not working fine

Comment: @ShreyanMehta `sequalize.import is deprecated now` can you provide source? since I use sequelize/cli `sequelize init` generate code with `sequalize.import` recently

Answer (score 3):

Might be helpful. This is what that code looks like for me when compiled:

```
/**
 * Imports a model defined in another file
 *
 * Imported models are cached, so multiple calls to import with the same path will not load the file multiple times
 *
 * See https://github.com/sequelize/express-example for a short example of how to define your models in separate files so that they can be imported by sequelize.import
 * @param {String} path The path to the file that holds the model you want to import. If the part is relative, it will be resolved relatively to the calling file
 * @return {Model}
 */
import(path) {
  // is it a relative path?
  if (Path.normalize(path) !== Path.resolve(path)) {
    // make path relative to the caller
    const callerFilename = Utils.stack()[1].getFileName();
    const callerPath = Path.dirname(callerFilename);

    path = Path.resolve(callerPath, path);
  }

  if (!this.importCache[path]) {
    let defineCall = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : require(path);
    if (typeof defineCall === 'object') {
      // ES6 module compatibility
      defineCall = defineCall.default;
    }
    this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
  }

  return this.importCache[path];
}
```